# Which rpm to have Korean in Redhat? (Only packages available in official DVD!)

Tags: unicode, fonts, redhat

I have a RedHat server where I need to have as many languages as possibile.
To have also Corean, i just need to install the additional packages:

```
libFS-1.0.0-3.1.x86_64.rpm
chkfontpath-1.10.1-1.1.x86_64.rpm
xorg-x11-xfs-1.0.2-5.el5_6.1.x86_64.rpm
fonts-korean-1.0.11-10.el5.noarch.rpm
```

But: those packages are not in the official redHat DVD (rhel-x86_64-server-7.2), and one of requirements is that I cannot use any package that is not there...

I see that the red hat version has translation in Korean, but somehow i cannot find the packages for Korean fonts. I suppose the font must be there... but which package?
Thanks to the next packages(*), I could install Chinese (traditional and simplified), Japanese.

```
#CJKuni = chinese, Japanese, Korean Unicode, but the Korean doesn't work:
rpm -Uvh cjkuni-uming-fonts-0.2.20080216.1-53.el7.noarch.rpm
rpm -Uvh cjkuni-ukai-fonts-0.2.20080216.1-51.el7.noarch.rpm
```

Any suggestion about the package I need to install? Remember, it must be in the official release DVD. Also other languages may be useful, for example, i also don't have Hindi.

(*)If you need languages on server and you can install any package you want, you can see my answer to another post for more details: ([display unicode characters on red hat server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4153938/display-unicode-characters-on-red-hat-server/)

Answer (score 1):

Ok, installing those helped:

```
#Korean
rpm -Uvh baekmuk-ttf-fonts-common-2.2-36.el7.noarch.rpm
rpm -Uvh baekmuk-ttf-batang-fonts-2.2-36.el7.noarch.rpm

#Package names for different languages of India and relatives have this format:
lohit-*fonts*.rpm
```

Generally list everything that contains the word -fonts- inside the name. Often you should know the language or font name in the original language (as in case of Batang)...